# Comint input and output text positioning

Tags: python, shell, comint

I'm using Emacs as a TCP client for a remote Python debugger I wrote. I can connect and interact with the server, but I'm not able to get the comint buffer used as the client to align input and output correctly.

To demonstrate, I execute `my_debugger_test.py`, pictured here for line numbers:

[image: code with line numbers]

The break point is hit, so I call `my-debugger-client-start` and a comint buffer opens, `*my-debugger-client*`.

[image: call my-debugger-client-start]

I enter `next`. This will tell the debugger to go to the next line. Instead, I get a syntax error telling me that the input was invalid. This is because whatever was sent to the debugger did not correspond to a `do_*` method and was not valid Python:

[image: invalid input]

I know this because if I put point at the start of one of the lines, I can call valid Python, such as `print("hi")` and the line will execute.

To demonstrate:

Move point to beginning of line

[image: Go to front of line]

Enter valid Python

[image: insert print function]

Press `RET` and the line evaluates

[image: the line evaluates]

We can see that "hi" was printed. Unfortunately, it was printed *after* the prompt. A NameError also shows up because the comint also sent `(MyDebugger)`. If I run a separate Python instance, I can get the same result:

[image: reproduce NameError]

It seems that putting point at the start of the last line works and that the comint is seeing the prompt as input text. Again, go to the start of the line. This time, insert `next` to execute the current line:

[image: enter next at the start of line]

[image: debugger moves to next line]

We can see the `y = 2` is printed showing us that the debugger executed `do_next` and moved to the next line.

Obviously, having the comint buffer behave like `*shell*` is desirable.

- How can I get output to appear above the prompt?
- How can I exclude the prompt when sending input to the debug server?

The server/debugger code is here. Type `help` in the client to see what commands it accepts. Currently, the prompt is defined in Python, the `self.prompt = f'({self.__class__.__name__}) '` line. Maybe it needs to be defined in elisp?

```python
# mydebugger.py

import pdb
import sys
import socket


class MyDebugger(pdb.Pdb):
    """

    Set up server/breakpoint in code:

        MyDebugger(host='0.0.0.0', port=4444).set_trace()

    Connect client:

        telnet 127.0.0.1 4444

    """

    def __init__(self, host, port, skip=None, complete_key='tab'):

        self.listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, True)
        self.listen_socket.bind((host, port))
        self.listen_socket.listen(1)

        connection, address = self.listen_socket.accept()

        self.stream = connection.makefile('rw', errors='ignore')

        self._old_stdin = sys.stdin
        self._old_stdout = sys.stdout

        sys.stdin = self.stream
        sys.stdout = self.stream

        pdb.Pdb.__init__(self, readrc=False)

        self.use_rawinput = False

        self.prompt = f'({self.__class__.__name__}) '

    def _clean_up(self):
        self.stream.close()
        self.listen_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        self.listen_socket.close()

        sys.stdin = self._old_stdin
        sys.stdout = self._old_stdout

    def do_quit(self, arg):
        self._clean_up()
        super().do_quit()

    def do_EOF(self, arg):
        self._clean_up()
        super().do_EOF()


def breakpoint():
    MyDebugger(host='127.0.0.1', port=4444).set_trace(sys._getframe().f_back)
```

The test code is:

```python
# my_debugger_test.py

def first(a, b):
    print(f"entered first", flush=True)
    return a + b


def main():
    print(f"entered main", flush=True)
    import mydebugger; mydebugger.breakpoint()
    x = 1
    y = 2
    return first(x, y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    value = main()
    print(f"value: {value}", flush=True)
```

Put `mydebugger.py` in the `site-packages` directory and run `my_debugger_test.py`.  It will break and start a debug server you can connect to at `127.0.0.1:4444`.

My Emacs client is modified from this [minimal TCP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162967/simple-tcp-client-examples-in-emacs-elisp). Instead of printing to a buffer, it sends a message to the minibuffer. It also creates a `*listen*` buffer. If `comint-mode` is turned on there, you can send input to the server.

I've modified the minimal client to write to the buffer associated with the process:

```lisp
(defvar my-debugger-client-port 4444
    "port of the server")

(defvar my-debugger-client-host "127.0.0.1"
    "host of the server")

(defun my-debugger-client-start nil
  "starts an emacs tcp client my-debugger-clienter"
  (interactive)
  (make-network-process
   :name "my-debugger-client"
   :buffer "*my-debugger-client*"
   :family 'ipv4
   :host my-debugger-client-host
   :service my-debugger-client-port
   :sentinel 'my-debugger-client-sentinel
   :filter 'my-debugger-client-filter)

  (switch-to-buffer "*my-debugger-client*")

  (with-current-buffer "*my-debugger-client*"
    (comint-mode)))

(defun my-debugger-client-stop nil
  "stop an emacs tcp my-debugger-clienter"
  (interactive)
  (delete-process "my-debugger-client"))

(defun my-debugger-client-filter (proc string)
  (with-current-buffer "*my-debugger-client*"
    (insert string)))

(defun my-debugger-client-sentinel (proc msg)
  (when (string= msg "connection broken by remote peer\n")
    (with-current-buffer "*my-debugger-client*"
      (insert (format "client %s has quit" proc)))))
```

Comment: Perhaps add an annotated screenshot to show the problem for people who might be able to help but aren't going to actually run and test your python code.

Comment: This smells like a prompt problem to me: see e.g. the contortions that Org babel sessions have to go through to deal with the prompt in the inferior process. But I haven't looked at your question in any detail, so I could be off by miles, if not by parsecs.

Comment: @NickD, that sounds reasonable.  I had looked at `shell` and `run-python` for how they handle prompts.  I had not thought to look at babel sessions. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer created by `make-network-process`, which was named `*my-debugger-client*` is what's called a process buffer.  These are described in the [Processes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Process-Buffers.html) section of the manual.

The manual says,

> The position to insert the **output is determined by the ‘process-mark’**,
> which is then updated to point to the end of the text just inserted.
> Usually, but not always, the ‘process-mark’ is at the end of the
> buffer.

Regarding input, the `RET` in a process buffer defaults to command `comint-send-input`. The help for this command says,

> After the process output mark, [comint-send-input] sends **all text from
> the process mark to point as input to the process**.

So, to answer the questions "How can I get output to appear above the prompt?" and "How can I exclude the prompt when sending input to the debug server?", you need to pay attention to where the process mark and point are.

As pointed out in the question, the prompt affects the calculation of input and output in regards to the process mark and point.  Searching the `comint.el` source, there are several variables dealing with prompts, `comint-prompt-regexp` and `comint-use-prompt-regexp`.  The first defines the prompt, the second tells Emacs to use the regexp to distinguish input and output regions.

Finally, there's the bookkeeping involved with using the prompt regexp to place text in the process buffer such that output is above the prompt and input is read from after it. That's exactly what the `comint-output-filter` function does.

So, all together,  set the `comint-prompt-regexp` and `comint-use-prompt-regexp` in the process buffer. Also, replace the `my-debugger-client-filter` to wrap `comint-output-filter`.

```lisp
(defvar my-debugger-client-port 4444
    "port of the server")

(defvar my-debugger-client-host "127.0.0.1"
    "host of the server")

(defun my-debugger-client-start nil
  "starts an emacs tcp client my-debugger-clienter"
  (interactive)
  (make-network-process
   :name "my-debugger-client"
   :buffer "*my-debugger-client*"
   :family 'ipv4
   :host my-debugger-client-host
   :service my-debugger-client-port
   :sentinel 'my-debugger-client-sentinel
   :filter 'my-debugger-client-filter)

  (switch-to-buffer "*my-debugger-client*")

  (with-current-buffer "*my-debugger-client*"
    (comint-mode)
    (setq-local comint-prompt-regexp "(MyDebugger) ")
    (setq-local comint-use-prompt-regexp t)))

(defun my-debugger-client-stop nil
  (interactive)
  (delete-process "my-debugger-client"))

(defun my-debugger-client-filter (proc string)
  (comint-output-filter proc string))

(defun my-debugger-client-sentinel (proc msg)
  (when (string= msg "connection broken by remote peer\n")
    (with-current-buffer "*my-debugger-client*"
      (insert (format "client %s has quit" proc)))))
```